# 悪意のあるサーバーに ssh することのリスクはあるか

Tags: security, ssh

悪意のあるサーバーに ssh してコマンドを実行することに対して、接続元へのセキュリティ的なリスクはありますか？

scp などでファイルを持ってきて実行したりなどすれば、それがリスクなのはわかりますが、逆に ssh してコマンドを打つだけならば、どのようなサーバーに ssh してもリスクはないのでしょうか？ (打ったコマンドが悪意の第三者に丸見えになる、打ったコマンドが意図通りに実行されない、以外にリスクはありますか？)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSHクライアントの脆弱性を突くように仕込まれたパケットを送信されて、クライアント側で任意のコードを実行されるなどで、OSごと乗っ取られる可能性があります。

過去に、OpenSSHやPuTTY、TeraTerm等のメジャーなSSHクライアントで、任意のコードを実行できるような脆弱性が存在したことがあります。脆弱性が修正されたバージョンを使用していなければ、大変危険です。また、 未知の脆弱性を利用された場合、防ぐことはほぼ不可能になります。

隔離された仮想環境で行う等の方法で可能な限りリスクを低減すべきでしょう。